# I don't understand the Azure App Insights Metrics graph with "sum" function?

Tags: azure-application-insights

The following graph shows a metric I'm collecting, with "sum" selected as the aggregation function, yet this does not look like it is summing the values from left to right in this graph??  Anyone know what I'm missing here?  I'm trying to get something more like the total cases of covid-19 graph, it just keeps building... it will always be a convex curve...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was answered in another thread, has to do with "Time granularity" setting...